# Scratch Org project-scratch-def.json features: do they matter for Enterprise and Developer Editions?

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, scratch-org-definition-file

Does the features property matter in the project scratch org I have messed around adding features from documentation on [Scratch Org Definition File](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm), but it doesn't seem to impact the scratch org configuration. For example, I have developed apex and lightning components without specifying the features.

**TL;DR**

**Is there a list of features that are not automatically turned on in Enterprise and Developer edition Scratch Orgs?**

```
  {
  "orgName": "MyCompany",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "features": []d,
  "settings": {
    "orgPreferenceSettings": {
      "s1DesktopEnabled": true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From a purely development standpoint, all of the basic code features are enabled for Developer and Enterprise orgs. The AuthorApex feature is for the Professional Edition with Apex add-on configuration (real Professional Edition orgs don't get Apex by default). You only need to specify settings that do not come enabled by default (e.g. multi-currency). The list of features not enabled is pretty significant. Imagine creating a new Developer Edition org on the standard sign up page--that's exactly what you get by default.

Comment: Gotcha, so basically to determine which ones you would need to turn on it is trial and error? I see the list of "Supported Features" but it doesn't indicate whether they would need to be turned on. Is this knowledge about default settings just acquired through more time in the platform?

Comment: @thinker As a matter of preparing for the future, I'd recommend that you always specify all features you need, even if the template already includes them. This is because unlocked packages depend on this file as well in order to make sure all dependencies are met. By specifying all the features you need, you'll make the transition to unlocked packages much smoother.

Comment: That is a great point about the managed packages. Makes sense, I didn't think about that. Thanks for your help #greenCheck.